# Neo4J remote shell -file flag not working

Tags: neo4j

I am having problems with Neo4J's shell's -file flag when running remotely. The command I'm running looks like this:

```
neo4j-shell -host <host> -port <port> -file data.cql
```

It connects, but says "No data returned, and nothing was changed." If I run that same command locally (removing host/port of course), it works successfully.

If I run the same Cypher statements using the -c flag, it works fine:

```
neo4j-shell -host <host> -port <port> -c "CREATE (person:Person {name: \"Foo\"})-[has:Has]->(skill:Skill {name: \"Bar\"});"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-file` option works as expected:

```
➜  neo4j-enterprise-2.2.5  cat ~/dummy.cyp
create (n);

➜  neo4j-enterprise-2.2.5  bin/neo4j-shell -host localhost -port 1337 -file ~/dummy.cyp
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
8 ms
```

Doublecheck if you terminate the cypher commands in your data.cql with a semicolon. If it still does not work check if input redirection works:

```
bin/neo4j-shell -host <myhost> -port <port> < data.cql
```

(not sure if that is possible on Windows - on Unices it it).

Comment: A query had been added without a semicolon which then caused subsequent matches to fail.